# Cube.js React QueryBuilder : "This month" and "Weekly" not getting data from start of week if month changes mid-week

Tags: reactjs, cube.js

I understand why `"This month"` combined with `"Weekly"` doesn't get the full week's data if the month starts at the middle. For example the week starting September 27th still shows as starting `2021-09-27` but the data is only taken from `2021-10-01` as the `"This month"` filter is set, it makes sense but sometimes we would like to get the full week even if the month changed midweek but we don't want to set a broader filter (`"This quarter"` or even `"This year"` are too many weeks to consider). I tried tracing the TimeDimensions function back and ended at the `"QueryBuilder"` component, on the `"updateTimeDimensions"` but it's imported `from '@cubejs-client/react'` so I cannot see what the component accepts as `"Time Dimension"` or if you can add an option of `"This month + full weeks"`. Does someone have any suggestion on how to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

you can always manipulate your dates in the front-end before feeding them to query time_dimensions.

Define a function that takes your dateRange ['2021-10-1', '2021-10-31'] and returns a dateRange that includes weeks completed, that's possible with date-fns or moment.js or day.js. and call that function when you select 'Weekly'.

here is an [imperative example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-date-fns-rnxnrs?file=src/app/app.component.ts) :

```
dateRange: any = [new Date('2021-10-1'), new Date('2021-10-31')];
startAndendWeeksIncluded = [
    startOfWeek(this.dateRange[0], { weekStartsOn: 1 }),
    endOfWeek(this.dateRange[1], { weekStartsOn: 1 }),
  ];
 
//OutPut ["2021-09-26T23:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-31T22:59:59.999Z"]
```